# Why doesn't this PDO rollback work?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO in PHP and a MySQL database. What I want to do is whenever an insert fails (such as duplicate entry in unique field), have it throw an exception error message  and roll back the changes (not to auto increment in my case).

This is what I've done, but it doesn't work:

```
try {
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];

    $query="INSERT INTO subscriber (Email,FirstName,LastName,CreateDate) VALUES (?,?,?,CURDATE())";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $email , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $FirstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $LastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="addSub.php"> Back</a>'); 
    $conn->rollBack();
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Here is the edit version of it (for whole part of inserting) , is that correct? thanks

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){


$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->beingTransaction();
try {

    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];


    $query="INSERT INTO subscriber (Email,FirstName,LastName,CreateDate) VALUES (?,?,?,CURDATE())";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);


    $stmt->bindParam(1, $email , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $FirstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $LastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $conn->commit();

}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="addSub.php"> Back</a>'); 
    $conn->rollBack();
    }


try {
    $userID = $_SESSION['username'];
    $query="INSERT INTO list_sub (SubID,ListID) VALUES ('',$_SESSION[ListID])";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    $conn->commit();

}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    $conn->rollBack();
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="addSub.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }

$conn = null;
}
```

Comment: I've edited this a bit so you receive some answers, but this is really quite localized. `die()` is rather, well .. self descriptive :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is that all the code? You have to start a transaction in order to commit/rollback:

```
$conn->beginTransaction();

try {
    ....
    $conn->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $conn->rollback();
}
```

Comment: is that mean change $stmt->execute(); to   $conn->commit();?

Comment: Also, what if i have more than one transaction (eg. insert two times. ) as my edit version.

Comment: No... $stmt->execute() still needs to happen, you call $stmt->execute() before you call $conn->commit(). Ill edit post in a few, slammed at work.

Comment: it is closed , can you see my edited post?

Comment: Ya, put the $stmt->execute() before the $conn->commit()

Comment: Let me know if you get it working or not. Just add back the $stmt->execute() and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 6):

The PHP function `die` is an alias for [exit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) and terminates the execution immediately after printing the specified message, so the second line - the rollback - is never executed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your use of `die()` will exit the program, so no lines after it will be executed.

However, aside from that there are other things you need to make sure are set.

First, Make sure `subscriber` is an `InnoDB` table type. The default table type on MySQL (`MyISAM`) does not support transactions.

Second, make sure your `PDO` object has `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` set to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. You can set this property in the constructor or using `setAttribute()`.

Third, you need to actually start a transaction with `$conn->beginTransaction()` before your `try` clause.

Comment: $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

add this at the top of the code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `AUTOINCREMENT` values are consecutive.

If there are two transactions in parallel, both inserting into the same table, then either one accepts that there are holes in the numbering, or that the second transaction has to wait until the first one has completed before it can start. As that would be bad for performance, the "holes are acceptable" variant is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

[Your put die...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)

> This language construct is equivalent to exit().